# Can I get an XmlObject instance if I have its corresponding SchemaType object?

Tags: xmlbeans

In XmlBeans, I have a compiled schema and I create an instance through the

`MyStuff  stuff = MyStuff.Factory.newInstance()` method.

But in a part of my application I need to treat MyStuff as a generic XmlObject and yet I want to create instances of it. Suppose that I want to do:

```
workWithObjectsAbstractly(stuff)
```

where workWithObjectsAbstractly is defined as:

```
public void workWithObjectsAbstractly(XmlObject o)
{
  .
  .
   SchemaType type = o.schemaType();
   XmlObject newInstance = type.???????   <--- is there such method?
  .
  .
  [Work with new instances as XmlObjects]
  . 
}
```

Is there a way to do that?
I could inspect the schemaType through Particles and Properties and then create stuff with
XmlCursor, but it seems cumbersome. Can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid this, `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xsd2inst.XmlSampleUtil` does this abstraction in order to create auto-generated, valid instances from a SchemaType.

In this case, it uses

```
XmlObject object = XmlObject.Factory.newInstance();
XmlCursor cursor = object.newCursor();
// Skip the document node
cursor.toNextToken();
// ... it then uses the cursor to add elements, attributes, etc
```

Hope that helps a bit...